# SignalR / malloc error - incorrect checksum for freed object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, malloc, signalr

I have been noticing random crashes in my application that all seem to have to do with SignalR-ObjC. The crash can occur either shortly after the SignalR data is received or after several minutes of receiving data.

The error message is:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbae292ce00: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The breakpoint gets placed on this line in the SRChunkBuffer.m file:

```
[_buffer appendString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

If I comment out my code that uses SignalR-ObjC to invoke a server-side method to subscribe to groups, this crash does not occur:

```
for (NSString *groupName in combinedArray ){
    [proxy invoke:@"Subscribe" withArgs:@[groupName] completionHandler:nil];
    }
```

I have made sure all my cocoa pods / dependencies for SignalR-ObjC are up to date, removed my loop for registering for groups and instead manually registered for them one at a time, and yet I still get a crash randomly.

I see mentions of potentially using @synchronized but not sure how that fits into this case.

How can I stop this crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by replacing my [connection start] with:

```
[connection start:[[SRLongPollingTransport alloc] init]]
```

Had to import "SRLongPollingTransport.h" to make this work...

Source: https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC/issues/243